# Automatically Save Attachments on Lotus Notes 9.0 (Mac)

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, email-attachments

My employer (unfortunately) uses a Lotus Notes server. All company computers are Windows machines, but I am a Mac user. I have configured my e-mail on IBM Notes 9.0 for Mac.

It's tolerable, but I need some help with AppleScript or automating some features. Most emails I receive are reports in MS Word or PDF format. I would like to automatically copy all attachments to a folder on the Desktop. Can I do this with AppleScript or Automator on the Mac? Can I do this with actions in the Notes software itself?

Comment: If a button or menu item in the Notes client on your Mac meets what you mean by  "actions in the Notes software itself?" then yes, using Lotusscript you can automatically save attachments in one click.

Comment: Unsolicited, but here's a bit of advice anyhow: when you say things like  "(unfortunately)" and "It's tolerable" about a product that you need help with, you might consider that the people who are most likely to be able to help you -- the ones who actually know and like the product -- just may be a little less likely to want to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Create a personal agent in your local replica of your mail database, which triggers on "when new documents are added".  In this agent (it should be LotusScript or Java), call LNDocument.Detach.  I do not believe that you can automatically detach from simple actions, but I have not doublechecked.

Be aware: Detach removes the file from the Notes document entirely.  This could cause problems with compliance or any number of other things, so you want to check with your IT department what the policies are supposed to be.  *Make sure you follow them.*  Compliance's job is to keep your company from suffering additional penalties that could exceed your annual salary twofold or more when there's a lawsuit.  (It's worse because when you replicate back up to the server, the changes you make to your local documents copy to the server and delete the attachments there as well.)